# Python error with subprocess.call() in loop

Tags: python, call, subprocess, popen, synchronous

I want to write a Python script that:

1. Reads all subdirectories in a directory (this is loop 1)
2. Reads the current image in subdirectory (not a loop because it only has one
   image)
3. After reading this image, fix something and write it to a new image
   in the current subdirectory.

All of this is OK, but when I try to run `subprocess.call()` with this new image, I have a problem:

new image -> subporcess.cal() -> new image 2

The 'new image 2' when generated from python script gives an error when opened (but if I try to run via command line or without looping through subdirectories, it works).

Here is my code as I described above:

```
for dayFolder in listDayFolder:
           output_dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data1) 

        warp = "gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' -ot Float32 -tps mecrator.tif " + fileName + ".tif";


       pipe = subprocess.call([warp], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place ... is that how the code actually looks? (because if so, it won't even run, but will instead give you an `IndentationError`).

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True`? You are not using any shell feature, the only thing you are doing is keeping open a security hole. Also, if you want to check stdout you can use `subprocess.check_output` (note that the documentation explicitly state to *avoid* setting `stdout=PIPE` in `subprocess.call` since this may cause a deadlock!).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the difficulty is in the fact that`fileName` is not being re-assigned. I'll bet that if you call `print warp` before you call `subprocess.call`, you'll notice a large number of repeats of the same command. Maybe you meant this:

```
warp = "gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' "+
       "-ot Float32 -tps mecrator.tif " + dayFolder + "/" + fileName + ".tif"
```